# FindByWhatever in ASP.NET Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity

In using ASP Identity (v2.1) I would like to be able to find users by more ways than the built in

1. FindByNameAsync
2. FindByIdAsync
3. FindByEmailAsync

Is is possible to write a `FindBySomeOtherField` method assuming I had extended the Identity models with additional fields? If so, assume I added an addition field called "MyNewField" that is an `int`. How would I write that method and make it work with ASP Identity?

Comment: The UserManager class is not sealed, you can provide your own inherited implementation that does that. Also you can extend the User/Identity models with your own properties and extend the DbContext with mappings for those properties. You then register your type with whatever injection service you are using and you are good to go.

Comment: Any chance you could show and example? Please also make it an answer so I can select it. Thanks.